# How to test individual testng methods when it depends on other methods

Tags: junit, testng, spring-test

Consider the following example code

```
public class PropertyServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
  @Test(groups={"property_service"})
  public void testCreateProperty() { ... }

  @Test(groups={"property_service"}, dependsOnMethods={"testCreateProperty"})
  public void testCreateProperty1() {...P
}
```

When I execute individual test 'testCreateProperty1' using maven,

mvn -Dtest=PropertyServiceTest#testCreateProperty1 
am getting the following exception.

Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException:
com.service.PropertyServiceTest.testCreateProperty1() is depending on method public void com.service.PropertyServiceTest.testCreateProperty(), which is not annotated with @Test

```
at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.findDependedUponMethods(MethodHelper.java:95)
at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.topologicalSort(MethodHelper.java:245)
at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.sortMethods(MethodHelper.java:316)
at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.collectAndOrderMethods(MethodHelper.java:51)
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried making your `@Test` methods `public`?

Comment: all the methods are public. I edited the qn as well.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be related to the *Spring TestContext Framework*.

Rather, this appears to be a configuration issue with TestNG.

You therefore might find the "[How to solve test method dependencies?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/ciy1C9Bt9FY)" discussion on Google Groups helpful.

Let us know if that helps you solve your issue.